# Wrap text around table in nested enumerate environments

Tags: lists, enumerate, enumitem, wrap, adjustbox

As a follow-up question to [Wrap text around table in itemize environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/387315/161388), I'd like to contain an `enumerate` environment **and** a table inside another `enumerate` environment. Right now, the table appears **outside** all nested `enumerate` environments.

```latex
\documentclass[10pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem, adjustbox, wrapfig, lipsum, enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \begin{adjustbox}{valign=T, raise=0pt, minipage={1.0\textwidth}}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[2]
    \item \lipsum[2]
    \item \lipsum[2]
    \end{enumerate}
    \begin{wraptable}{r}{.1\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} \hline
            Sample Text & Sample Text & Sample Text\\ \hline
            Sample Text & Sample Text & Sample Text\\ \hline
            Sample Text & Sample Text & Sample Text\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{wraptable}%
    \lipsum[2]
\end{adjustbox}
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Instead of trying the `wrapfig` approach, I'd go for the `cutwin` approach as `wrapfig` as never ment to work correctly when used inside of or even near of list environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple to do with the plain TeX macro package `insbox`. It defines an `\InsertBoxR` command with two mandatory arguments: the number of lines  unshortened before the box is inserted in the following paragraph and the box contents, and one (last) optional argument, the number of supplementary lines to shorten, in case TeX doesn't make a correct computation. In addition, as we are inside a list, we have to compensate  for the list  leftmargin, which is lost in the process. To do so, I added  `\leftmargini` to `\leftskip`.

```
\documentclass[10pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage{enumitem, adjustbox, wrapfig, lipsum}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{insbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[2]
\item
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \lipsum[2]
    \item \lipsum[2]
    \item \lipsum[2]
    \end{enumerate}
\InsertBoxR{0}{
        \begin{tabular}{@{}|c|c|c|@{}} \hline
            Sample Text & Sample Text & Sample Text\\ \hline
            Sample Text & Sample Text & Sample Text\\ \hline
            Sample Text & Sample Text & Sample Text\\ \hline
        \end{tabular}}
\addtolength{\leftskip}{\leftmargini}
    \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2-5]
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

With the basic settings taken from [Ross' answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387324/134144) to the previous question, you can get the following result using the `cutiwn` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{cutwin}


\begin{document}


\opencutright 
\renewcommand\windowpagestuff{% setup the image to be placed in the cutout
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l l}
            \hline
            Some random text & More random text\\
            Some random text & More random text\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular} 
}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[2]
\item 
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \begin{adjustbox}{valign=T, raise=0pt, minipage={1.0\linewidth}}
    \begin{cutout}{0}{0.40\linewidth}{0pt}{3}\lipsum[2]\end{cutout}\end{adjustbox} 
    \item \lipsum[2]
    \item \lipsum[2]
    \end{enumerate}
    \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[2]
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While this solution does work, it seems to require additional fine-tuning and adjustments when contents change. I'll keep looking for a more automated or clean solution, but thank you for your answer!

Comment: Probably interesting: [Wrapfigure in an enumerate environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232105/134144), [Problem with wrapfig and itemize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/208429/134144), [Will it ever be possible to use wrapfig with an enumerate or itemize environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/59101/134144)